# How to print the S3 key name in python

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.8

I have added S3 trigger for all puts of new objects and invoke AWS Lambda.

My Lambda is written in Python 3.8 to parse through the key object and file and fetch the filename.

```
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        print(key)
```

Once I upload **mys3bucket/jsonfiles/2021/05/31/file.json**

My code prints **jsonfiles/2021/05/31/file.json**,
what I would like to print instead is.

```
key1 as 2021/05/31/, omitting the jsonfiles prefix
and
key2 as file.json, printing just the file name.
```

What should my code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you got the `key` do some string parsing and get your required data from it,

```
>>> s = "mys3bucket/jsonfiles/2021/05/31/file.json"
>>> s.split("jsonfiles/")
['mys3bucket/', '2021/05/31/file.json']
>>> req = s.split("jsonfiles/")[1]
>>> ind = req.rfind('/')
>>> req[:ind]
'2021/05/31'
>>> req[ind + 1:]
'file.json'
```